# Heat Pump GE Blower Motor Rotating In The Opposite Direction

Tags: furnace, heat-pump, blower, motor

I bought a used GE 5KCP39GG R359S 1/3hp Motor, 200/230V, 1080rpm, Trane PN: D800349P01 Blower Motor that is exactly the same model as the one I’m replacing. The problem is that the newer (used) motor is working but rotating counterclockwise when the label on the motor indicates that it should be clockwise, which is what I need for my furnace. Everything is connected exactly as the motor before, which is identical. Why is the newer (used) motor rotating in the opposite direction indicated on the label and is there a way I can reverse the rotation?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the wiring please